# INSERT Syntax error (missing operator) in vb.net fform

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert

Inside my application, I need to insert data from two sources: table and form textbox. So I tried to use the code below, but the message box is displaying an error. (Edit: I am using vb.net)

**Error:**

```
while inserting record on table ..Syntax error (missing operator) in query
```

**Code:**

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DellXPS\Desktop\mDB.accdb"

        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t2(f3) SELECT f1 @Eid FROM t1 WHERE f11=true "
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Eid",  OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Would you mind to add the name of the programmer language which you have used?

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the select statement in your command text.

```
SELECT f1 @Eid FROM t1 WHERE f11=true
```

What are you trying to achieve here? Is F1 a column? What does TextBox1.Text (the source of parameter @Eid) contain?

I'd suggest taking a look at SQL select statement syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp).

Comment: sorry u are right :) that what i need
insert value from tow source the first is table1 and the Second is text box on form  
"INSERT INTO table2(column3) SELECT column1 @parameter FROM table1 WHERE column11=true "

Comment: It's still not clear! If you are trying to insert two bits of data into two columns you need to specify the second column to insert into. If you wish for both bits of data (all values from column1 in table1 where column11 = true AND the value of the textbox) to go into table2, you will need to UNION two the two together:
`INSERT INTO table2(column3) SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column11=true UNION select @parameter`.
The third option is that you're trying to append the two values together, in which case it's a matter of a "+" between column1 and @parameter in your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the select part of your query, it is invalid.

```
INSERT INTO t2(f3) SELECT f1 @Eid FROM t1 WHERE f11=true
```

Basically the operator is missing on this section of code:

> ... SELECT f1 **operator missing here** @Eid FROM ...

If you could tell us what you are trying to insert, we will be able to guide you further. You are also trying to select more fields than you are inserting which, I assume, will cause you another error

Addendum 1:

In response to your comment, you will need:

```
INSERT INTO t2(f3, <Name of extra column>) SELECT f1, @Eid FROM t1 WHERE f11=true
```

Since you are inserting 2 columns, you need to specify 2 columns in the insert part of the query. Replace `<Name of extra column>` with your other column name

Comment: i have 2 tables i need to insert data from table1 to table2 and with text from textbox on form.
I hope to be clear and thanks lots of  Stuart Blackler

Answer (score 0):

I haven't set up a development enviroment for vb.net, but two things are suspisious for me:

- The position of the call `cmd.Parameters.Add(...).value` must be placed before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will be executed. See [this example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/26770).
- The parameter `TextBox1.Text` could be null. If so, the sql statement will be incomplete for the engine.

Comment: sir reporter i placed  cmd.Parameters.Add(...).value before cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and the Problem still

Answer (score 0):

use following code to add parameter with value

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eid",   TextBox1.Text);
```

Then execute

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Put + operator between f1 and @Eid in Insert statement like below sql statements:

```
INSERT INTO t2(f3, <Name of extra column>) SELECT f1 + @Eid FROM t1 WHERE f11=true
```